# how to shift text in next line if particular text not adjust in single line in android

Tags: android

```
String text = "This is my first program ***Hello World*** please print in text view "
TextView mytextview = findviewID(R.id.textview);
mytextview.setText(text);
```

i have text view i want  whose with is fix 50dp  i want to set  text in text view such manner so that if Hello World will not adjust in first line then we have to  shift Hello World next  line if it will adjust in single line then we have to keep in same line .

please suggest me how i will do this thanks 
e.g
Yes like suppose e.g

```
Scenario 1 : This is my first program **Hello World** 
            please print in text view -> correct 
Scenario 2 : This is my first program 
             **Hello World** please print in text view -> correct 
Scenario 3 : This is my first program 
             **Hello World** please print 
             in text view -> correct 
Scenario 4 : This is my first program **Hello 
             World** please print in text view -> Wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the layout_height option of your Textview as **wrap_content**, the text should automatically adjust itself.

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is my first program ***Hello World*** please print in text view/>
</LinearLayout>
```

gives an output like so:

[image]

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you can also use something like this,

```
String s = "This is my first program"
       + System.lineSeparator()
       + "Hello World"
       + System.lineSeparator()
       + "please print in text view";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but you understand  wrong i think  you  assume width 100 or 150 dp i means fix what i expecting if in 100 or 15o dp hello world fix then it should come in first line else it should come  next  line not like which you have done and yes we kept layout height as wrapt content what i am thinking if Hello World if we can assume one text then it will work but i dont know how to make Hello World as one TextView Thanks

Comment: @MARSH So basically, you are looking for something that can give you the measurement of a String in dp before it prints to the TextView? Something like a function that will return true or false depending on the length in dp of a string?

Comment: Yes like suppose e.g
Scenario 1 : This is my first program ***Hello World*** 
                    please print in text view -> correct
Scenario 2 : This is my first program 
                     ***Hello World***  please print in text view -> correct
Scenario 3 : This is my first program 
                     ***Hello World***  please print in 
                     text view -> correct
Scenario 4 : This is my first program  ***Hello 
                     World***  please print in text view -> Wrong
above we want in text view .let me know if any query Thanks